# Status bar color on ios7

Tags: colors, ios7

My question would be that how can you set the status bar to a default color in ios7. (Like in the latest update of Facebook and Twitter app)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The status bar doesn't have a color - it's transparent. The color you are seeing in the new Facebook app is the *navigation bar* that has been extended under the status bar. In iOS 7 your status bar can be transparent with white text, transparent with black text, or opaque (black). It can't be tinted, but you can give the illusion of a tint by extending your navigation bar.

iOS 7 introduces the concept of extendable view edges to allow for this sort of thing. You might want to review the UI transition guide or `UIViewController` documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can assign a background image to the navigation bar and whatever alpha/ opacity that image has, will be picked up by the status bar.

Create your image 640x128 and whatever colour/pattern you want.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This will make the picture the background of the navigation bar and the status bar.